# Disable Aero Snap and Movement of window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, fullscreen

I have some kind of "kiosk" window that should stay maximized at all costs, but can be minimized (but not moved).

My implementation is pretty simple:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    //Remove the window style after maximizing, to avoid covering the task bar.

    StateChanged += (o, args) =>
    {
        if (WindowState != WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        }
    };
}
```

To avoid losing the minimize animation, when the user clicks to minimize, return the window style.

```
private void Minimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

This code makes the window fullscreen, without the title bar and disables the drag-to-move.

The problem is that I still can move and resize the window with the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right/Top/Bottom</kbd> keyboard shortcuts.
Also the window can be moved using the right click on the taskbar (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring the window context menu, selecting "Move" or "Restore").

I tried to use the `ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize` (together with the other two properties) but it makes my window bleed into the sides of the screen.

Manually sizing the window is a no-go.

So, why is my window being shifted in position when I use `Maximized` + `None` + `CanMinimize`? Is there a way to properly adjust the window?

[image: Bleeds]

*As you can see, the window goes beyond the size of the screen. I need to avoid that.*

Comment: Aero Snap does not use any special messages to do its job.  So you will not get any event you can intercept to alter what it does.  The frame animation it shows is completely out of your control, your program is not involved at all.  You can at best see the resulting LocationChanged and SizeChanged events when the user accepts the proposed new frame position.  In general, it doesn't make much sense in a kiosk app to try to support both ways.  And above all, you configure the machine to be suitable to act as a kiosk.  Like disabling Ctrl+Alt+Del for example.  And disabling Aero Snap.

Comment: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/enable-and-disable-aero-snap-docking-windows-7/

Comment: Well, `Aero Snap` can be disabled for a single window, with the combination of `Maximized` + `None` + `CanMinimize`, but I find a little bit odd that the window gets cut because of that combination. See image above.

Comment: That's entirely normal, happened because you removed the border.  So the window no longer uses the proper maximize bounds that were returned by WM_GETMINMAXINFO.  Consider changing the WindowStyle first before you change the WindowState.  Not actually sure if WPF will do it right then, you may have to intercept the message.